# Logic Apps For Each

Tags: azure

I am try to utilise the For Each object in logic apps and I am not sure if this is possible:

Step 1 - SQL Stored Procedure is executed returning a number of rows

Step 2 - For Each based on the number of rows in Step 1

Step 2a - Execute a SQL Procedure based on values in loop

The problem I am finding is that when I add the loop, it states that there is no dynamic content available even though Step 1 will return results.

I've googled and there seems to be no information on using the for each loop in Logic Apps.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're working on a fix for this. Before the fix is available, try one of these two workarounds:

- If you're comfortable with code view, create a for-each loop in designer, then specify `ResultSets` as the input for *foreach*.
- Alternatively, add a *Compose* card after the SQL action, choose `ResultSets` as the input. Then use the `Output` of the *Compose* card for for-each loop.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately its by design: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types#powershell-runbooks

I resolved it by calling the SP's in parallel via Logic Apps.
(note: when you do so, don't forget to hit 'Publish' runbook in order for the input variables passed to be picked up correctly)